# Is it possible to convert RCA(video only) to Arduino Uno then to a computer?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, project-critique

I have an old wireless RCA output camera. I was wondering if I can convert its analog input to a digital one and have it saved on a file in my laptop?

Comment: yes, get a USB video digitizer with an RCA input ... plug into your laptop

Comment: Not possible with the Arduino Uno. The composite video signal has an analog bandwidth of ~5MHz, and a 16MHz Arduino with its 12-bit ADC has a max sample freq of circa 77kHz. You cannot sample the signal fast enough and you also can't send it to the computer fast enough due to the incredibly slow serial interface. You'll a need a faster chip (high-speed ADC and DMA..). See https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/composite-video-signal, http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/373389B-01/nivms/signals_cvbs/ https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=6549.0

Comment: Is it possible? Technically, yes - after all the ZX Spectrum had the [Videoface](http://live.worldofspectrum.org/infoseek/magazines/your-sinclair/12#52). Only good for still images though (sampled the image in sections across many many frames - 0.26 seconds per image, so about 6 frames needed to get an image depending on region), and 4-bit graphics (fed though a few comparators). Would it be worth doing it? No. Unless you only wanted the experience of doing it. Would the results be usable? No. Absolutely not. Would I do it? No. I'd get a USB video capture dongle.

Comment: Thank you! Still got lots of things to learn.